# LaTeX, как сделать такой шрифт

Tags: шрифты, latex

Шрифт виден на изображении, как такой сделать?

[image: шрифт]

Comment: Может, это `mathcal{nl}`?

Comment: нет, mathcal только для заглавных букв

Comment: Вот, взгляните: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479/lowercase-mathcal.

Comment: там ответ, надо писать как \ell

Comment: Но `\ell` только буква `l`. Вам только она нужна?

Comment: этого хватило, n - выглядит одинаково

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)